# Techniques for merging two separate and moving camera shots

Tags: editing, camera, multi-camera

'The Man From U.N.C.L.E.' (2015) contains a neat break-in scene that shows a special force team arriving and infiltrating an industry area. A few seconds of this scene really got me and I wonder how it was shot:

At around 1:30 there is a moment when both protagonists are captured by separate cameras, from separate angles and with even some shaky motions applied. The screen is split and shows those two shots at the same time. The cameras are turning and lining up and finally the black bar (that were separating the frames) gets removed. The "third" shot (fullscreen, now both actors) continues a free hand kind of movement.

[YouTube: 'Invasion' scene at mentioned time stamp](https://youtu.be/zxod_reabtc?t=50)

How was this achieved or could have been achieved?